# Isomorphism between two families of curves over the Teichmueller space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, teichmuller-theory, analytic-geometry

In his construction of the [Teichmueller space](http://www.numdam.org/article/SHC_1960-1961__13_2_A4_0.pdf)  of curves of genus $\geq 2$ Grothendieck states in Corollaire 2.4 that the map $$\underline{Isom}_S(X,Y) \xrightarrow{} S$$ is **finite**. The map represents the functor of isomorphisms between the two families of curves over S.

I understand that the fibres are finite. Hence one is left to prove **properness**. I know the valuative criterion of properness Lemme 2.5.

But I do not understand: Why does Grothendieck invoke Lemme 2.5 to prove Cor. 2.4? Why does Cor. 2.4 satisfy the assumption of Lemme 2.5, i.e. why
$$u_K:X_K \xrightarrow{\simeq} Y_K \implies u:X \xrightarrow{\simeq} Y$$
i.e. why does isomorphy of the two families over a Zariski open subset of $S$ imply isomorphy over all of $S$?

Comment: Could you explain what is it you don't understand? Lemma 2.5 is exactly the expression of the valuative criterion of properness for $\underline{Isom}_S(X,Y)$, and Lemma 2.6 contains the proof.

Comment: @abx I made an edit to my question.

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand (and I will stop trying). "why does isomorphy..." is what you have to prove (for the valuative criterion), and this is what Grothendieck proves in the Lemma.

Comment: @abx Sorry for the inconvenience concerning my question. So let me just ask: How do you prove Corollary 2.4? According to which logical steps? Thank you.

Comment: As you say, we want to prove properness applying the valuative criterion. In our case, this amounts exactly to prove Lemma 2.5. Then we (I mean, Grothendieck) reduce this Lemma to Lemma 2.6, which we prove.

Comment: @abx OK. Now I understand the logic of the proof: The proof of Lemme 2.6 and a posteriori Cor. 2.4 builds on the fact that all morphisms from P^1 to a curve of genus >= 2 are constant (Riemann-Hurwitz), analytically speaking. Thank you for helping :-)